# Flutter Asynchronous Suspension

Tags: flutter

I am trying to get my flutter app to display my current location. While there is no error for my code displayed in the debug console, the emulator just keeps loading without displaying any result. I suspect that there is some form of asynchronous suspension that is going on but am not sure how to fix it.

This is the file that I use to get my current location (geolocator_services.dart):

```
import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class GeolocatorService {
  Future<Position> getCurrentLocation() async {
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
      desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high
    );
  }
}
```

This is the file that I use to store my location data (application_bloc.dart)

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:hawkepedia/services/geolocator_Services.dart';

import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';

class ApplicationBloc with ChangeNotifier {
  final geoLocatorService = GeolocatorService();

  //Variables
  Position? currentLocation;

  //fire function when the app starts
  ApplicationBloc(){
    setCurrentLocation();
  }

  //gets current location
  setCurrentLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await geoLocatorService.getCurrentLocation();
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

This is the file which I use to display the geolocation data in my app (maps_mainpage.dart).

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hawkepedia/blocs/application_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
class MainMaps extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainMaps({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainMapsState createState() => _MainMapsState();
}

class _MainMapsState extends State<MainMaps> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final applicationBloc = Provider.of<ApplicationBloc>(context);
    return Scaffold(
      //if this is the first time loading the app
      body: (applicationBloc.currentLocation == null)
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
        : ListView(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search Location'),
            ),
              Container(
                height: 300.0,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(applicationBloc.currentLocation!.latitude, 
                    applicationBloc.currentLocation!.longitude),
                    zoom: 14),
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, it seems that you aren't calling the `setCurrentLocation` , or the returned value of your method is null. Did you put a breakpoint to see which case is? I'll wait an for your answer.

Comment: Hi @ricarDEV, this is what is displayed in my debug console:
E/flutter (13197): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13197): #2      GeolocatorService.getCurrentLocation
package:hawkepedia/services/geolocator_Services.dart:5
E/flutter (13197): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (13197): #3      ApplicationBloc.setCurrentLocation
package:hawkepedia/blocs/application_bloc.dart:19
E/flutter (13197): <asynchronous suspension>
/flutter (13197):
F/crash_dump32(13293): crash_dump.cpp:474] failed to attach to thread 186: Permission denied

Comment: Maybe you should grant permission to the geolocator, as it recommend in the doc's:
permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
  if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
    permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
    }
  }
check the readme file of the plugin where it gives you the example. Aparently it's a permission problem

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your Scaffold into Consumer widget, Make sure you have also wrapped MaterialApp with Relevent Provider widget in order to use this.

```
     late final applicationBloc;  
     @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
         applicationBloc=  Provider.of<ApplicationBloc>(context);   
       applicationBloc.setCurrentLocation();
      }
```

then,

```
 Consumer(builder:(context,child) {
  return Scaffold(
      //if this is the first time loading the app
      body: (applicationBloc.currentLocation == null)
        ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),)
        : ListView(
          children: [
            TextField(
              decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search Location'),
            ),
              Container(
                height: 300.0,
                child: GoogleMap(
                  mapType: MapType.normal,
                  myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                  initialCameraPosition:
                    CameraPosition(target: LatLng(applicationBloc.currentLocation!.latitude, 
                    applicationBloc.currentLocation!.longitude),
                    zoom: 14),
                ),
              )
          ],
        ),
    );
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi Hammad, as I am still a beginner, would you be able to advice which dart file I should use the late final applicationBloc in?

Comment: Check out my complete answer, Let me know if that works out

Answer (score 0):

Before call `Geolocator.getCurrentPosition()`, we need to check location service is enabled and we have location permission or not.

```
bool enabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
if (!enabled) {
  //do something
  return;
}

LocationPermission permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();

if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
  //do something
  return;
}

if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
  // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.      
  AppSettings.openLocationSettings();
  return;
}

try {
  _position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();      
} catch (e) {
  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out then let me know
maps_mainpage.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:hawkepedia/blocs/application_bloc.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:untitled/export.dart';

class MainMaps extends StatefulWidget {
  const MainMaps({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MainMapsState createState() => _MainMapsState();
}

class _MainMapsState extends State<MainMaps> {
  late final applicationBloc;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
    applicationBloc = Provider.of<ApplicationBloc>(context);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (_) => ApplicationBloc(),
      child: Consumer<ApplicationBloc>(builder: (context, value, child) {
        return Scaffold(
          //if this is the first time loading the app
          body: (value.currentLocation == null)
              ? Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              : ListView(
                  children: [
                    TextField(
                      decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Search Location'),
                    ),
                    Container(
                      height: 300.0,
                      child: GoogleMap(
                        mapType: MapType.normal,
                        myLocationButtonEnabled: true,
                        initialCameraPosition: CameraPosition(
                            target: LatLng(
                                applicationBloc.currentLocation!.latitude,
                                applicationBloc.currentLocation!.longitude),
                            zoom: 14),
                      ),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Hammad, I got this error: The following assertion was thrown building Builder:
dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType<_InheritedProviderScope<ApplicationBloc>>() or dependOnInheritedElement() was called before _MainMapsState.initState() completed.

Comment: remove ChangeNotifierProvider widget from build() method and Wrap your MaterialApp with this.  ChangeNotifierProvider(create(_) => ApplicationBloc(), child: MaterialApp());

Comment: Hi Hammad, currently in my main.dart, the ChangeNotifierProvide already wraps the MaterialApp. I tried to remove the ChangeNotifierProvider from the appplication_bloc.dart, but that just gives me an error in the main.dart file.

Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
        create: (context) => ApplicationBloc(),
        child: MaterialApp(
          title: 'Flutter Demo',
          theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        ),
        home: MainMaps(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Comment: Can you elaborate exactly what error you are encountering?